# How to pass a List from Controller to View

Tags: spring, list

I'm using MongoDB and Spring.  I get the following error message when the variable `list1` is passed to the View:

> cannot to cast array list ....

Can someone see what I may be doing wrong?

Controller:

```
    @Controller
    public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    ItemRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    Test66Repository repository66;

    @RequestMapping("/items/findAll")
    public String showItemList(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("items", repository.findAll());

        List<test66> list1 = repository66.findAll();


        model.addAttribute("list1x", ((test66) list1).getX());
        model.addAttribute("list1y", ((test66) list1).getY());

        return "items/item_list";       
    }
```

View

```
    </script>
      <canvas id="ChartDemo"></canvas>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
        <span id="timeToRender"></span>
        <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
           <canvas id="ChartDemo"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
        <input id="list1x" type="hidden"  th:value="${list1x}"/>
            <input id="list1y" type="hidden"  th:value="${list1y}"/>
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        var ctx = document.getElementById("ChartDemo").getContext('2d');
        var ChartDemo = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                // コントローラーで格納したlabelを変数式で取り出すだけ。
                labels: /*[[ ${label} ]]*/,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Chart-1",
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                        lineTension: 0,
                        fill: false,
                        // 上記と同様、pointを変数式で取り出しているだけです。
                        data: /*[[ ${point} ]]*/,
                    },
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
            }
        });
        /*]]>*/
        </script>
```

Comment: Focused title.  Simplified the questino and removed extraneous wording.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check `repository66.findAll()` returns a `List` or a `Iterable`.

Comment: Hey guy, so what about `((test66) list1).getX()` and `((test66) list1).getY()`. What data type are they return?

Comment: hi,They return Integer.

Comment: And list. xhtml type array? I try to transform from list to array. I failed.